# How to convert string to date and calculate using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column that storage the year and month like this

```
start  | end
202101 | 202212
201905 | 202001
```

The format is YYYYMM

I need to convert the two columns in date and get the difference in months between 'start' and 'end' columns

Comment: Have you read about MySQL date functions like STR_TO_DATE() and DATEDIFF()? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @BillKarwin Hi, I know the function str_to_date, but my tablet have only then year and month, dont have the day. And the format is YYYYMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you get 2021-01-00 if you just use str_to_date(), which makes the date invalid to use for datediff() or timestampdiff().

```
mysql> select * from t;
+--------+--------+
| start  | end    |
+--------+--------+
| 202101 | 202212 |
| 201905 | 202001 |
+--------+--------+

mysql> select str_to_date(start, '%Y%m') as start,
    str_to_date(end, '%Y%m') as end from t;
+------------+------------+
| start      | end        |
+------------+------------+
| 2021-01-00 | 2022-12-00 |
| 2019-05-00 | 2020-01-00 |
+------------+------------+
```

You can fix this by appending '01':

```
mysql> select str_to_date(concat(start, '01'), '%Y%m%d') as start,
    str_to_date(concat(end, '01'), '%Y%m%d') as end from t;
+------------+------------+
| start      | end        |
+------------+------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2019-05-01 | 2020-01-01 |
+------------+------------+

mysql> select timestampdiff(month, str_to_date(concat(start, '01'), '%Y%m%d'), 
    str_to_date(concat(end, '01'), '%Y%m%d')) as diff from t;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|   23 |
|    8 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

use str_to_date

```
select datediff(str_to_date(end, '%Y%m'), str_to_date(start, '%Y%m'))
```

or for a valid day (month begin)

```
select datediff(str_to_date(end, '%Y%m01'), str_to_date(start, '%Y%m01'))
```

Comment: the `str_to_date` works, but the date result is `2021-01-00` and `2022-12-00`, so when use `datediff` this return `null`

Comment: answer  updated..